# Solve $y''+(1-2x \cos x \cos 2x)y=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation
$$y''+(1-2x \cos x \cos 2x)y=0 \space $$

Comment: Variations of constants?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: it could be an option I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Is that actually $2xy \cos x \cos 2x$ on the right hand side? For then you'd actually have the homogeneous equation $$y^{\prime\prime} + (1-2x\cos x \cos 2x)y = 0.$$ If not, and the $y$ is a typo, Giuseppe Negro's suggestion should work.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić: it's not a typo, but $2xy \cos x \cos 2x$. I'm rather unexperienced in ODE area, and thank you for your question that is welcome at this point.

Comment: Your best choice is to find an approximate solution using power series techniques.

Comment: @Chris'ssister - you still have the extra $y$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I see. Thank you. (+1)

Comment: @nbubis I'm afraid I bungled my original edit---the question's statement should now be correct.

Comment: @Chris'ssister - do you have a initial point you're looking for a solution in the vicinity of?

Comment: @nbubis: no, I don't have any initial point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best choice is to find an approximate solution using power series techniques. Here is few terms of the series with initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1.$

$$ y \left( x \right) =1+x-\frac{1}{2}\,{x}^{2}+\frac{1}{6}\,{x}^{3}+{\frac {5}{24}}\,{x}
^{4}-{\frac {37}{120}}\,{x}^{5}.$$

However, if you are interested in finding a solution close to the point $x=0$, then you can consider the differential equation

$$ y''(x)+y(x)=0, $$

which is easy to solve. Here are the plots. The first corresponds to the power series solution and the second to the equation $y''(x)+y(x)=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks for your suggestion (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister: You are welcome.